# Как узнать что закачка данного файла уже идет соседним приложением?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, сеть

Есть два (собственных) приложения на одном компе, они могут качать с сервера одно и то же (делать одну работу два раза). Чтоб это предотвратить, нужно одному приложению узнать, что другое уже качает данный файл с сервера (о файле мы конечно знаем все в обоих приложениях).

Нужны любые идеи как это можно осуществить.
(не рассматриваем случай, когда файл качается в одно и то же место, это не гарантированно, и с этим вариантом понятно как узнать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, выделить загрузку в отдельное приложение(процесс), у которого оба ваших приложения просят загрузить файл. А уже этот загрузчик можно сделать "синглтоном" в системе, он единственный будет загружать тот файл.

Другой вариант - писать временный (или постоянный) файл с состоянием требуемого файла: загружен ли он, может быть, путь расположения.

Comment: Ну так как одно из двух приложений - это уже постоянно запущенный в фоне сервис, то качать только им.Только (немного не догоняю) как к нему обращаться с запросом (сообщением)? по локальной сети? А вариант с состоянием можно дполнить до хранения состояния в регистрах.

Comment: Не обязательно сервис. Это может быть третье приложение. А два первых вызывают исполнение его. Если первое вызывает загрузчик, он, например, создаёт файл (lock). Второй экземпляр загрузчика увидит lock и сообщит вызывающему кодом ошибки. В некоторых случаях состояние - это зло, но тут, вроде, применимо.

Answer (score 4):

Приложения просто могут докладывать друг другу, что они делают. Для этого существуют именованные каналы, aka пайпы. В Qt за это отвечает [QLocalSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html). Это если вас не интересует ситуация, когда файл загрузили, потом приложение закрыли, потом открыли новое и качают заново тот же файл.

Если же ситуация интересует, надо организовывать какое-то транзакционное хранилище (базу данных), куда все приложения будут отчитываться о загруженных файлах и том, куда эти файлы были сохранены.

Причем базу стоит взять готовую (SQLite?) потому как реализовывая такое хранилище самостоятельно, вы будете вынуждены сами повторно реализовать 70% функционала базы данных. Вам оно надо?

Comment: @Mira, такое хранилище лучше файлов, голосую за него)

Comment: @LXA После закачки файлы и так устанавливаются в нужное (одно определенное) место, так что проблема именно со временем закачки. Но, хоть это и странно (для меня) тим лид одобрил другой вариант - что все скачивается одним приложением, остальные обращаются к нему. Так что по павилам СО помечаю ваш ответ )

Comment: @Mira - ваш лид знает толк в извращениях, я смотрю. Вам предстоит занятный ммм... процесс с созданием ВВС (Великого Велосипедного Сервиса) загрузок. 
А что будет, когда сервис будет падать... О, это просто экстаз.

Плохой, негодный лид.

Comment: @Mira а кто вам мешает сразу при начале закачки создавать файл и лочить его на запись? И ни одна живая душа не сможет такой же файл создать и в него писать. Имя может быть разным? Ну, HTTP позволяет md5 файла с сервера стянуть (и этим md5 обозвать), как раз для такого случая.

Comment: @gbg я честно защищала вариант с лоченным файлом. Сделала все что смогла ) по поводу велосипеда - дело в том что загрузчик учитывющий все фак-апы уже написан (ежики плакали и кололись...) конечно чую придётся его на других либах переписывать. Но это уже совсем другая история )

Comment: @Mira Загрузчик с обработкой всех факапов называется libcurl и написан, вероятнее всего, не вами. Ваш лид молодец - любит убить время на писание велосипедов (а также роликов, скейтбордов, лыж) всех мастей.